# Problem with Goal Performance in idempiere

Tags: performance, adempiere, idempiere

Goal Performance calculation is taking the last value entered instead of the current value that was typed before recording. Would that be normal? Someone could help me to solve this, I am new in this type of system and also in programming with Java.

Sorry if there are any English errors in the sentences, I'm new to this language!

Comment: Hi Rafael, your English is fine. Can you give more info about what you mean by "last value entered" and "current value entered"? What is the performance measure trying to do?

Comment: So dude, the image below you can see the fields I'm working on right now. It was not allowed to put the text in the comment because of the character limit, I put it in the image.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sNe1d17IlNW4uCyTS1F2APKgG0HR-GW9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Edit: And the Goal Performance calculation is performed by (Measure Actual / Measure Target), in this case 7180416.4 / 10000000.1

Comment: This would be the problem that I explained in the image, it takes the previous value, so it was to get the 10000000.1 in case

Comment: If anyone can help me I will be very grateful